# How to pass STL containers as arguments to BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, stl

For example, say we have this class which we want to test:

```
struct TestMe {
  vector<int> getSomething();
}
```

And the test function is made of:

```
...
vector<int> Expected;
TestMe TM;
...
Result = TM.getSomething();
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(Result, Expected);
...
```

STL vector provides a free operator==, but it does not provide an operator <<, so this code does not compile.
How can I get this to work? Can i define my own operator << ? What would its implementation look like? Extra credit to the most generic solution :)

Comment: There's no such thing as an `operator< <`, do you mean `operator<` or `operator<<`?

Comment: I suppose `get` is supposed to be `getSomething`. What does `operator<<` have to do with anything? `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL` uses the `==` operator.

Comment: @Potato: Yes, but if the check fails, it tries to print out the two values using `operator<<`. Thus `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL` requires both `operator==` and `operator<<`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS`, this tests each element and also prints where the mismatches are:

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(Result.begin(), Result.end(), Expected.begin(), Expected.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Philipp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836397/how-to-pass-stl-containers-as-arguments-to-boost-check-equal/4837404#4837404) is the best answer.  However you can make your own templated `operator<<()` that will work for vectors and other standard containers if you want:

```
// Will write out any container that has begin(), end() and a const_iterator type
template <typename C>
std::ostream& output_container(std::ostream& os, C const& c) {
    for (typename C::const_iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) {
        if (i != c.begin()) os << ", ";
        os << *i;
    }

    return os;
}

// Overload operators for each container type that forward to output_container()
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector<T> const& c) {
    return output_container(os, c);
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, list<T> const& c) {
    return output_container(os, c);
}
```

Although you could simply rename `output_container()` to `operator<<()` and get rid of the per-container-type `operator<<()` templates, thereby catching *all* attempts to use `<<` on a class type, this could possibly interfere with `operator<<()` function templates for other types.

Comment: I tried a very similar solution before posting my question, but it did not compile. I copy-pasted your solution and get the same error: error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=uint8_t
1>        ]

Comment: @zr: It sounds like name lookup is failing.  Are you sure that all these templates are defined before they are used?

Comment: @zr: Also it looks like you're actually using a `vector<uint8_t>`, not `vector<int>` as advertised -- is that so?  Otherwise I'm confused.

Comment: @JRH: The answer to both questions is yes. In the example i used an int for simplicity.

Comment: @zr: I suspect the problem is that `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL()` expands to a call to a template function (let's call it `f()`) which calls `operator<<()`, and that *at the point `f()` was defined*, our `operator<<()` template was not.  If that's the case, then you'll need to put a forward declaration (`template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<T> const&);`) *before* #including the Boost headers that define `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL()`.  (I know, yuck.)

Comment: @zr @j_random_hacker:
`Boost` defines free function `operator<<`s like
`template< class C, class T >
basic_wrap_stringstream<C>&
operator<<( basic_wrap_stringstream<C>&, T const& )`
in `namespace boost`.
So, compiler can't find your `operator<<` in global scope because of ADL.
If we enclose our `operator<<` by `namespace std`, the compiler will find the
operator.
However, according to 17.4.3.1 in the standard, this results in
undefined behaviour unfortunately...

Comment: @Ise: That's useful to know, but it looks like that overload requires a `basic_wrap_stringstream`, which will require an implicit conversion, making it less specialised than my `operator<<()`.  But I don't believe that's the underlying problem anyway, because if it was then the compiler would find that Boost's overload when my template is absent, and when my template is present the result would be either (a) the compiler still prefers the Boost overload or (b) an "ambiguity" error message, not a "no operator found" message.

Comment: @zr @j_random_hacker: It's difficult to describe in a comment, but...
`Boost test library` is defined in `namespace boost`.
So if the compiler sees an `operator<<`, first the compiler searches in
`namespace boost`, and finds candidates.
If `boost test library` isn't defined in `namespace boost`, or if there aren't
candidates, the compiler will search in global scope.
Sorry, probably I can't explain in more detail in a comment.

Comment: @Ise: Thanks, but I *suspect* that's not quite right after grovelling through 14.6.4.2 and 3.4.2 in the standard.  It seems that, provided the name doesn't turn out to be a method, both "ordinary" lookup and lookup in associated namespaces and classes (e.g. in namespace `boost`) will take place, and overload resolution will take place on the *union* of all names found.  I can't spend more time on this unfortunately, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, a way to customize the output string to print integers in hex. Injecting an operator into the std namespace would work, but every BOOST_CHECK in my test would be printed in hex.

So I injected some custom operators in the boost namespace that I could control with some global bools.

See my answer here [boost-check-fails-to-compile-operator-for-custom-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572583/boost-check-fails-to-compile-operator-for-custom-types/21946103#21946103).