# BOOST_CHECK fails to compile operator<< for custom types

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I wrote this really trivial class so that it's clear what my problem is:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A(int y) {x=y;}
    bool operator==(const A &other) const {return x==other.x;}
};
```

Now, if I define     A first(1) and A second(1), it would seem natural to me that BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(first, second) should pass. However, I got 50 errors when trying to do this, the first one sounds like: no math for operator << in ostr << t which is somewhere in the boost code... Other tests work just fine, comparing known types or even pointers, but there is something different that appears to happen with class objects.

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: It doesn't compile... And I'm working in Codeblocks so I can't copy-paste the errors. And all of them are in the file test_tools.hpp and I don't really understand what they are about (I mentioned the first one in the post). Should I give more examples?

Comment: I compiled with gcc and I would like to paste the errors but it is 11400 characters too long for a comment.

Comment: According to [this reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/reference/BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL.html) `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL` will print the values of non-equal arguments, so the macro expands to code which probably contains something like `cout << first << " != " << second`. Thus you have to define an output operator for your class (a non-member function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&)`).

Comment: That sounds weird, does everybody do this when using unit tests? Isn't there some other way of checking?

Comment: Just give us the errors generated by a single call to the macro and that should help a lot.

Comment: Accomplishing this is trickier than it might seem, and it's not well-documented.

Answer (score 27):

There are three ways I have identified to solve the problem with `operator<<`.

The first way is to provide an `operator<<` for your type.  This is needed because when `boost_check_equal` fails, it also logs the failure by calling `operator<<` with the objects.  See the verbose addendum after the break to see how this is actually accomplished.  It's harder than it might seem.

The second way is to not do the logging I just mentioned.  You can do this by `#definine`ing `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE`.  To disable logging for just one test, you might surround the test in question with this `#define`, then immediately `#undef` it:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL (first, second);
#undef BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE
```

The third way is to sidestep the need for an `operator<<` that works with your type by not comparing one item to another, but just checking a bool:

```
BOOST_CHECK (first == second);
```

Select your preferred method.

---

My preference is the first, but implementing that is suprisingly challenging.  If you simply define an `operator<<` in global scope, it won't work.  I think the reason for this is because of a problem with name resolution.  One popular suggestion to fix this is to put the `operator<<` in the `std` namespace.  This works, at least in practice on some compilers, but I don't like it because the Standard prohibits adding anything to the `std` namespace.

A better method I found is to implement a custom `print_log_value` class template specialization for your type.  `print_log_value` is a class template useb by the Boost.Test internals to actually call the correct `operator<<` for the specified type.  It delegates to an `operator<<` to do the heavy lifting.  Specializing `print_log_value` for your custom types is officially supported by Boost [citation needed], and is accomplished thusly.

Assuming your type is called `Timestamp` (it is in my code), first define a global free `operator<<` for `Timestamp`:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Mdi::Timestamp& ts)
{
    os << "Timestamp";
    return os;
}
```

...and then provide the `print_log_value` specialization for it, delegating to the `operator<<` you just defined:

```
namespace boost { namespace test_tools {
template<>           
struct print_log_value<Mdi::Timestamp > {
void operator()( std::ostream& os,
    Mdi::Timestamp const& ts)
{
    ::operator<<(os,ts);
}
};                                                          
}}
```

Comment: I understand, thank you, I'll do a simple boost_check () for now, since I really need to test some things pretty urgently, but I'll consider the other methods for later.

Comment: At least as of boost_1.61.00 you have to specify the  `print_log_value` template inside `boost::test_tools::tt_detail`.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation of the problem and solution. Yet another variation is that you may simply add an ``operator<<`` to the ``boost::test_tools::tt_detail`` namespace rather than specializing ``print_log_value``. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40747110/3154588) below for more details with the proper formatting.

Comment: Maybe it's my version of Boost, but I find that `BOOST_CHECK(a == b);` still requires `operator<<`, but you can trick it into cooperating with `BOOST_CHECK((a == b))`

Answer (score 5):

This is a supplement to the excellent [answer from John Dibling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573165/3154588). The problem seems to be that there needs to be an output operator in the right namespace. So if you have a global output `operator<<` defined, then you may avoid this error (at least with Visual Studio 2015, aka vc14, and boost 1.60) by defining another one in the `boost::test_tools::tt_detail` namespace that forwards to the global operator. This minor tweak enables one to avoid a strange and more verbose specialization of the `print_log_value` class. Here is what I did:

```
namespace boost {
namespace test_tools {
namespace tt_detail {
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Mdi::Timestamp const& ts)
{
    return ::operator<<(os, ts);
}
}  // namespace tt_detail
}  // namespace test_tools
}  // namespace boost
```

While it has been three years since this question and answer have been posted, I have not seen this discussed clearly in the [Boost.Test documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Wouldn't importing the operator be preferrable? `namespace boost::test_tools::tt_detail { using ::operator<<;}`?

Comment: Sure, if that works. Your solution is more succinct.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [John Dibling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241536/john-dibling)'s answer I was looking for a way to dump integer values in HEX rather than decimal I came up with this approach:

```
// test_macros.h in my project
namespace myproject
{
namespace test
{
namespace macros
{
    extern bool hex;

    // context manager
    struct use_hex
    {
        use_hex()  { hex = true; }
        ~use_hex() { hex = false; }
    };

 }; // namespace
 }; // namespace
 }; // namespace

namespace boost
{
namespace test_tools
{

    // boost 1.56+ uses these methods

    template<>
    inline                                               
    void                                                 
    print_log_value<uint64>::                       
    operator()(std::ostream & out, const uint64 & t) 
    {                                                    
        if(myproject::test::macros::hex)                    
            out << ::boost::format("0x%016X") % t;           
        else 
            out << t;                                        
    }                                                    

namespace tt_detail
{

    // Boost < 1.56 uses these methods

    template <>
    inline
    std::ostream &
    operator<<(std::ostream & ostr, print_helper_t<uint64> const & ph )
    {
        if(myproject::test::macros::hex)
            return ostr << ::boost::format("0x%016X") % ph.m_t;

        return ostr << ph.m_t;
    }

}; // namespace
}; // namespace
}; // namespace
```

Now in my unit test case, I can turn on/off hex by setting the global static bool value, for example:

```
for(uint64 i = 1; i <= 256/64; ++i)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0) test::macros::hex = true;
    else           test::macros::hex = false;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i+1, dst.pop());
}
```

And I get the behavior I was looking for:

```
test_foobar.cc(106): error in "test_foobar_51": check i+1 == dst.pop() failed [2 != 257]
test_foobar.cc(106): error in "test_foobar_51": check i+1 == dst.pop() failed [0x0000000000000003 != 0x0000000000000102]
test_foobar.cc(106): error in "test_foobar_51": check i+1 == dst.pop() failed [4 != 259]
test_foobar.cc(106): error in "test_foobar_51": check i+1 == dst.pop() failed [0x0000000000000005 != 0x0000000000000104]
```

Alternatively, I can use the context manager:

```
{
    test::macros::use_hex context;

    for(uint64 i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    {
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i + 0x200, i + 0x100);
    }
}

for(uint64 i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i + 0x200, i + 0x100);
}
```

And hex output will only be used in that block:

```
test_foobar.cc(94): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [0x0000000000000201 != 0x0000000000000101]
test_foobar.cc(94): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [0x0000000000000202 != 0x0000000000000102]
test_foobar.cc(94): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [0x0000000000000203 != 0x0000000000000103]
test_foobar.cc(94): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [0x0000000000000204 != 0x0000000000000104]
test_foobar.cc(100): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [513 != 257]
test_foobar.cc(100): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [514 != 258]
test_foobar.cc(100): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [515 != 259]
test_foobar.cc(100): error in "test_foobar_28": check i + 0x200 == i + 0x100 failed [516 != 260]
```

Comment: +1:  Just saw this now, and I'm a fan.  Something like this is very handy when trying to dump things like UDP packets.

Answer (score 3):

There is a clean way starting Boost 1.64 to log user defined types via the *customization points*. The full documentation of this feature can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/test_tools_support_for_logging/testing_tool_output_disable.html).

An example from the documentation is given below. The idea is to define the function `boost_test_print_type` for the type you want to print, and to bring this function into the test case (found via ADL):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE logger-customization-point
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

namespace user_defined_namespace {
  struct user_defined_type {
      int value;

      user_defined_type(int value_) : value(value_)
      {}

      bool operator==(int right) const {
          return right == value;
      }
  };
}

namespace user_defined_namespace {
  std::ostream& boost_test_print_type(std::ostream& ostr, user_defined_type const& right) {
      ostr << "** value of user_defined_type is " << right.value << " **";
      return ostr;
  }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1)
{
    user_defined_namespace::user_defined_type t(10);
    BOOST_TEST(t == 11);

    using namespace user_defined_namespace;
    user_defined_type t2(11);
    BOOST_TEST(t2 == 11);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't have to define the BOOST_TEST_MODULE variable. I also had my operator<< already defined on the global scope, so I modified my code to look like this in the test file:

    namespace foobar {
        std::ostream& boost_test_print_type(std::ostream& os, const mytype& foo {
            return ::operator<<(os, foo);
        } 
    }

I might end up putting these common things into a test helper file since I have several compilation units and test files.